# How to uninstall armory from ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, software-uninstall

I have recently installed Bitcoin [Armory](https://bitcoinarmory.com/) in my computer. Unfortunately I don't have enough space, so I wish to uninstall it for now. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
sudo apt-get remove $(dpkg -l armory)
```

If it doesn't work, try

```
sudo apt-get remove $dpkg -l |grep armory)
```

If even this doesn't work, try this guaranteed method.

```
cd <folder where .deb file is stored>
dpkg -r <name of package>.deb
```

Comment: dpkg -r <name of package>.deb worked, Ty

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18, had originally installed [Armory 0.96.0 for Ubuntu/Debian 64-bit with GCC 5.3](https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/download/), and uninstalled it now with:

```
sudo apt remove armory
```